# Chrome link bug, adding styles that are not even defined (I think)

Tags: css, google-chrome

On my website I have links that are as follows, (shortened for easiness)

```
<a><h2 class="playerBar"></h2></a>
```

The css rule that is buggy is,

```
.playerBar {border: 1px solid #222;}
```

Here is an image of what it looks like **before** the link has been visited,

http://www.images.novactown.com/eg1.png

Notice that it is on the **Friends** tab.

To create the buggy effect click on the first `h2` and it will take you to that person's account page. Once there switch the tab from **Account** to **Friends** and then click on the first h2 again, switching tabs to **Friends** again and you will get something like this...

http://www.images.novactown.com/eg2.png

I have tried setting `a:visited` but nothing happens, and it only happens in chrome (tested in IE and MOZ)

Here is the link to the problem

http://www.novactown.com/account?id=1#_friends

(Also this bug only occurs when starting on the **Account** tab and then switching to the **Friends** tab if you load up the **Friends** tab from the start all works well)

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Man that's weird, taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's rendering `outline-color: red;` on your anchor tag.

I'd try setting `outline:0`, or  `outline-color: none;` on your li/anchor.

Comment: I would also check out http://www.xldstudios.com/using-a-proper-css-reset-vs-quick-blunt-wildcard-reset/

Comment: What makes it even weirder though if you create the buggy effect and hit f5 it then displays them normally!